# How to use the Search API in SDL LiveContent Architect from C#

Tags: sdl-tridion, tridion-docs

we have a C# Browser application, where we have to provide a search functionality. This search is to be implemented using SDL LiveContent Reach (XQuery Search API) because we have our product documentation being created by SDL Create.
So we wanted to know how to get the data from SDL Search API and display it in our dialog using our own formatting (massaging the search result for styling).

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Can you please elaborate and clarify what you are trying to achieve exactly? Note that most users here have a background in Tridion Sites, so Tridion Docs questions will have to be crystal clear. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is a CR 7.x search functionality available by using **/web/search.xql**

Please refer to [offical documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20LiveContent%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-11FC5AEF-924C-4D50-9B5E-A4833B9838B2#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+LiveContent+full+documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dreach%2520api&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1441784529053&currentQuery=reach%2520api&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-B771EA71-264E-4681-9C11-15636F8F951D&query=&scope=&filename=GUID-9B000ACF-0E6B-43D7-A6D7-F245D68EF991.xml&docid=GUID-B771EA71-264E-4681-9C11-15636F8F951D&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=&toc=false)

Example URL:

```
http://<host>:<port>/<context>/web/search.xql?action=search&min=<value>&chunk=<value>&max=<value>&sort=<value>&scope=<value>&query=<value>&searchId=<value>&format=<value>&lang=<value>&pub=<value>&filter=<value>
```